# How to display multiple webgrids in same page -- asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I want to display two webgrids populated with same model in a same page, but one grid is not displaying much data rather the other grid is displaying full data.After doing following code i am getting exception like `Column "Quantity" does not exist` if i sort quantity column of second grid, how to solve this issue. here is my code

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, 
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 

<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)),
            grid.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description")
     )) 
</div>

     @{
    var gridsecond = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "secondgridContent");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 

<div id="secondgridContent">
    @gridsecond.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: gridsecond.Columns(
            gridsecond.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            gridsecond.Column("Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)),
            gridsecond.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description"),
            gridsecond.Column("Quantity", "Quantity")
     )) 
</div>
```

i am following the link shown below 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Please include your model definition.

Comment: i am following this link ie same model http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: @ Travis J i am curious about it, is it doable??

Comment: @Jaimin Soni i did that already without any luck